# bitbucket access not working

Tags: git, bitbucket

Not sure what happened, but all this time I was able to pull, push, clone etc from git using bitbucket. But after I changed my password online, it asks me for the password to my account, and then says:

```
fatal: Authentication failed
```

Is there any reason for this? My password is definitely correct. I'm not even able to clone to a new folder entirely!

Btw, i'm using `git version 1.8.0`. I upgraded it recently, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Is this access not working from your computer (ie using ssh/with git client), or when logging in on the website?

Comment: i'm using MacOSX Mountain Lion, the terminal

Comment: no idea why, but it's working with `gitx`, atleast I can use that for the time being I guess. But this makes no sense to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue.

Running push with -v doesn't help at all. Since I also only recently upgraded to git 1.8.0 I tried downgrading and got the same error, so it was either some other package or something on their end.

What I ended up doing (and also something I should have done long ago) is setting up ssh instead of using https. If that is also your case go to [Using the SSH protocol with Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket) and follow the instructions.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket -- Page was moved

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a bug with bitbucket. I think it's fixed now. They did not properly support 1.8.0

Comment: So is this fixed for > 1.8.0? I'm currently running 1.7.10.4 and getting this error.

Comment: Working for me in `1.8.0`. However, I never had this issue in `1.7+`, not sure about `1.7.10.4` since I don't think I had that specific version.